# What are some examples of algorithmic applications of noncommutative rational identity testing?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, polynomials, algebraic-complexity

The problem of [polynomial identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_testing) (PIT) is known to be in $\mathsf{RP}$, but not known to be in $\mathsf{P}$.

The related problem of [noncommutative rational identity testing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7782923) (NCIT) is known to have a *deterministic* polynomial algorithm.

I've seen many algorithmic applications of PIT, that work by reducing the detection of some combinatorial object (e.g. existence of a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph) to the verification that a polynomial corresponding to that object is nonzero.

Are there any analogous algorithmic applications of NCIT?

Comment: Here's an example of an application of non-commutative *polynomial* identity testing to an old problem in automata theory: https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/james.worrell/multi-tape.pdf